# Panel not actually taking full size when maximazing form

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

[the first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KzwP.png)

[the second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBjmH.png)

If i increase the size of the panel in the Designer window (Form1.cs[designer]) then the "blue box" is increased too! I have also set the anchor top, left, right, bottom but nothing happens. I cannot draw outside this blue box. I have enabled and disabled the autosize option in the properties section of the panel but still nothing happens.

Comment: attach `OnSizeChanged` to form panel, and resize the panel on this event

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with your draw logic. It somehow only takes the startup widht/height. Try setting it at startup as big as you can and then try drawing.

Comment: Have you tried “Dock=Fill”?

Comment: Please show the code in designer.cs.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I recommend that you use a Dock property like this image.
At first, you can make a 4 panels. panel 1 is dock = Top.
panel2 is dock = fill and panel2 has panel3 & 4 which has Left and Fill property each.
Panel4 area will be drawing area.

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use anchor properties**

[image]